# Kivy launcher and dependencies/third party libraries

Tags: kivy

I'm developing a kivy aplication which depends on a third party library.

How can i set/install this library in android to be able to test my app in kivy launcher? Is it possible or do I have to compile the app with buildozer?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy the whole library to your project directory so that it's locally available to be imported.

I would just use buildozer though, once it's set up it's just as easy as mucking around with kivy launcher (I would say even better). If your module is available via pip, you can just put its name in the buildozer.spec `requirements` field.

As a point of interest, you can in principle compile your own kivy launcher with your extra module, I think there is a python-for-android command line option for doing so. This isn't a very nice solution though, compared to the other two options.

Comment: Increment, I tried your suggestion without success. My external modules are pydictionary and pyttsx. I have pip installed it somewhere, so I go to their dis-packages directory and copy the folders 'pydictionary' and 'pyttsx', then I paste them onto my app's folder with main.py, buildozer.spec and bin folder. I then run 'buildozer android debug', it was able to compile but it can't be opened.

Comment: @KubiK888 try `import site; site.add_site_dir('./pyttsx')` etc